# With Compression option in SQL Server 2012 is not working

Tags: database, sql-server-2012, compression, backup

I am trying to take backup of my DB. I am using the following SQL code for this:

```
DECLARE @SharedPath nvarchar(100) = 'C:\Program   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup'
                DECLARE @filename VARCHAR(200)
                SET @filename = @SharedPath++'\Test.bak'
                BACKUP DATABASE [Test] 
                TO  DISK = @filename 
                WITH COMPRESSION
```

But with compression option is not working and bak file is getting created without compression. Operating system is Windows Server 2012. Its SQL Server 2012 Enterprise version.

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Nope, I do not. It creates Database backup file without compression.